How to update reference path of chunk files in main compressed bundle (.gz)?
Requirement: Use React lazy loading and also compress bundled files to .gz.
What am I doing:

Implemented lazzyloading of multiple containers which created
different bundles.

Eg.

main.min.bundle.js
chunk1.min.js
chunk2.min.js
chunk3.min.js


Used compression-webpack-plugin to compress min files to .gz files and deleted original files.

Eg.

main.bundle.min.js.gz
chunk1.min.js.gz
chunk2.min.js.gz
chunk3.min.js.gz

Issue:
While running the application, "main.bundle.min.js.gz" file is actually trying to load "chunk1.min.js" file as path of this file in the main.bundle file is not updated may be.
Query:
Anyways to resolve this issue or I should not gzip chunk files?
